# Category of Sets with only monomorphisms

Tags: category-theory

I came to work with a category which is the category of sets, "Sets", but for which I consider only arrows that are monomorphisms (i.e. injective maps).

This makes sense in particular when expressing the inverse function as a pullback functor.

Is there something in particular for this restricted Sets? A name? Some adjective to qualify shortly what we did when removing all non-mono arrows? Is it the result of some fundamental action?

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. What about expressing inverses as pullbacks requires you to restrict your attention to monomorphisms? In any case, the corresponding category with finite sets is called FI, and people spend a lot of time studying "FI-modules" these days in connection with homological stability, configuration spaces, etc.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but the Sub functor which takes an object (in a category, $\mathcal{C}$, with pullbacks) to the set of it's equivalence classes of monomorphisms can instead be viewed as being a functor from $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ to the category of preordered sets, i.e. [(0,1)-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%280%2C1%29-category). We can consider this an [indexed (0,1)-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indexed+category).

Comment: @Qiaochu Let $i_{V,U} : V \rightarrow U$ an injective map, let $f : A \rightarrow U$ a map, then $i_{f^{-1}(V),A} : f^{-1}(V) \rightarrow A$ is the pullback of $i_{[V,U]}$ along $f$. So we could say that $f^{-1}$ _is_ the functor pullback along $f$, except that this does not make sense when we apply this pullback functor to something other than an injective map.

Comment: @Qiaochu Thank you a lot for the pointer to FI. I just got aware that this FI category is just abstract sets with partial permutations.

Comment: @Derek Thank you very much for pointing out how we can switch to posets from this category. This makes sense. However I have a little trouble with your wording: what are the equivalence classes of monomorphisms? An other thing, did you mean subfunctor instead of Sub functor?

Comment: @almaus I meant what I said.  [Both](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject#as_classes_of_monomorphisms) are explained on the [nlab page for subobjects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject#the_poset_of_subobjects).

Comment: @Derek This is perfect, thank you for this link that is very clear. And indeed for the usage that I want to do the Sub(Sets) category is the most pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

It perfectly makes sense to talk about the inverse image functor in the full category of sets. Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a set-theoretic map: by the universal property of pullbacks, it induces an ajunction
$$ f_\ast : \mathsf{Set}/X \rightleftarrows \mathsf{Set}/Y : f^\ast $$
where the left adjoint $f_\ast$ is just the postcomposition by $f$ andthe right adjoint $f^\ast$ is the pullback along $f$. The link with the usual naive notion is that the pullback of a mono is always monic.

Now, as for your question about the category of finite sets and injections, I encountered it under the name $\mathsf{Inj}$ in the context of *nominal sets*. They are sheaves over $\mathsf{Inj}$ for the [Schanuel topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Schanuel+topos) and are studied by theoretical computer scientists as it provides an algebraic context to study name-binding.

Comment: MO did not ask for set finitness but still it is interesting.

Comment: @Pece Thank you very much! But what bothers me is, how can we be so sure that _this_ extension of the inverse image functor to the whole Sets is the "good" one? Cannot we build another functor, that is equal to the inverse functor on the monos, and is different from this pullback on everything else? Might it be that, philosophically, this is the only simple functorial extension to Sets?

Comment: @Jérôme I will probably address the issue of building a pullback upon the pathological "object" Sets in a different question ;) But you are right, this is quite important...